# Only run forward with AutorunSequencing

Tags: manipulate, animation

I'm trying to animate a graph that jumps between values at a critical point. What I've done is:

```
Manipulate[Show[Plot[a x + a, {x, -1, 0}, PlotRange -> {All, {-2, 2}}], Plot[a x + a, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {All, {-2, 2}}, PlotStyle -> Thick]], {a, 1.5, 1}, {a, -1.2, -1.5}, AutorunSequencing -> {1, 2}]
```

And this, almost works, except the AutorunSequence insists on going forward and reverse through the number range. I would like it to run from `a=1.5` to `a=1` and then jump to `a=-1.2` and continue to `a=-1.5`.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This is doable with `ListAnimate[]`

```
sh[a_] := 
 Show[Plot[a x + a, {x, -1, 0}, PlotRange -> {All, {-2, 2}}], 
  Plot[a x + a, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {All, {-2, 2}}, 
   PlotStyle -> Thick]]

list = Catenate[{Table[sh[a], {a, 1.5, 1, -0.05}], 
    Table[sh[a], {a, -1.2, -1.5, -0.05}]}];
ListAnimate[list]
```

[image]